# Effects library for flash or flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I'm looking for a effects library for flex or flash, I used one in a project but I cant remember the name. It doesnt matter if it's not free or open-source. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out http://www.flasheff.com/

looks like it's popular and easy to use

(no affiliation btw)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking of [Efflex](http://code.google.com/p/efflex/)